# Oracle sql order by with case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am facing difficulty in understanding oracle(12c) sql order by clause with case statement.
I have a table with the below data,

```
SELECT DEPT_NO, DEPT_NAME FROM SORTNG_LOGIC;

DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME          
---------- --------------------
     1 FINANCE             
     2 ACCOUNT             
     3 HUMAN RESOURCE      
     4 AUDIT               
     5 TRAINING
```

I am executing the below sql query for this table to add custom order, on oracle sql developer.

```
SELECT DEPT_NO, DEPT_NAME FROM SORTNG_LOGIC ORDER BY (
CASE DEPT_NAME
WHEN 'ACCOUNT' THEN '1'
WHEN 'AUDIT' THEN '2'
WHEN 'FINANCE' THEN '3'
ELSE '4' END
)DESC;
```

This is giving the below result :

```
DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME          
---------- --------------------
     3 HUMAN RESOURCE      
     5 TRAINING            
     1 FINANCE             
     4 AUDIT               
     2 ACCOUNT
```

But I expected that, the result should be

```
DEPT_NO DEPT_NAME          
---------- --------------------
     5 TRAINING            
     3 HUMAN RESOURCE      
     1 FINANCE             
     4 AUDIT               
     2 ACCOUNT
```

As I am sorting the dept_name in descending order, I thought'Training' should be above 'human resource'.

Where is my understanding going wrong? Could someone please explain this in detail?

Comment: how about using decode instead of case with order by? or bring this to select part and using it in subquery to sort?

Comment: Why do you expect that version? You have 4 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1. How do you distinguish between 4 and 4 ? You don't have `WHEN 'HUMAN RESOURCE' THEN '4'
ELSE '5' END` ... Isn't it enough to have just `ORDER BY DEPT_NAME DESC` in your case?

Comment: I can use DEPT_NAME desc but I would like to understand order by with case statement. Thanks\

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the department name in descending order, then you have to include that information in the query:

```
ORDER BY (CASE DEPT_NAME
              WHEN 'ACCOUNT' THEN 1
              WHEN 'AUDIT' THEN 2
              WHEN 'FINANCE' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
          END) DESC,
         DEPT_NAME DESC;
```

There is no reason for the value of the `CASE` to be a character string.  The logic really calls for a number.  If you use strings, then values larger than 9 will not work as you expect them to.

Comment: I have one doubt, on using order by with case statement and order by desc on the same column,  why oracle doesn't replace the result of one with another order by statement? May be a dumb question but out of curiosity

Comment: @JohnySam . . . There are two keys for the `order by`.  They are different.  Oracle doesn't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with decode function, basically does the same thing.

```
SELECT DEPT_NO, DEPT_NAME 
  FROM SORTNG_LOGIC 
 ORDER BY 
decode (DEPT_NAME,'ACCOUNT','1','AUDIT','2','FINANCE','3','4') DESC;
```

Comment: Nimesh, I tried with decode but no change in the result.
However, I dont need the alternatives for the result but I would like to understand how the ORDER BY with CASE statement works. If I understand the concept I can utilize it in better way rather than trying alternatives.

Comment: As mentioned by @engineer, both `HUMAN RESOURCES`, and `TRAINING` are being assigned as 4 so they won't be sorted as per your wish unless you explicitly tell the DB by providing additional `case when` or some other method. In this case I assume it's returning `HUMAN RESOURCES` first as it's stored first in the database and then comes `TRAINING`.